# Is possible to bypass the 32 bit limitation in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Can you help me please? I have got server for research purposes, where I have used MongoDB. But in this time size of my data exceed 2 GB limit. I do not any possibility of migrating to 64 bit. version. Is possible to bypass the 32 bit limitation in MongoDB some way please? Or it is definitely the end of my research on this system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could configure sharding  because 2Gb limit only applies to individual mongodb processes.
Pls refer the documentation
[sharded-clusters](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/sharded-clusters/)

Comment: thanks, but it is for sharing across multiple servers? I have only one server. Unfortunately I do not know MongoDB in depth, I use it only with one special tool, can you give me more detailed practice please?

Comment: @user41060 Yes once go though the documentation you will understand and I also found Python Script to set-up sharded environment on a single machine. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-snippets/blob/master/sharding/simple-setup.py

Comment: Your OS is 32-bit? else i dont understand why you cannt upgrade.